# Group by count does not provide correct result

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have two tables:

[image]

And

[image]

I want below expected output:

[image]

I tried below query:

```
SELECT con.container_id, count( si.item_id) as shipment_item_count,
 count(distinct si.shipment_order_id) as shipment_order_count, 
 count(si.shipment_order_id) as total_number_of_shipment_item --- Here how to show total number of shipment_item
 from shipment_item_container con
 left join shipment_item si on si.item_id = con.shipment_item
 group by con.container_id;
```

But it shows below output:

[image]

Comment: Please explain how the "4" is calculated.  "2" looks correct to me.

Comment: At shipment_item table SHO1 repeat 4 times. So, how to output this number?

Comment: 2 is the correct value, unless you want to calculate SHO1 as independent from the initial join. In this case you need a subquery, but why SHO1? If you had another value there, like SHO2, would it not be counted?

Comment: If SHO2 has no relation with shipment_item_container table, then that should not counted. Here count is based on shipment_item container table, but I need extra count of shipment_order_id if any member has any relation with shipment_item container table.

Comment: @TiagoSilva, Does subquery supportted with count-group by?

Comment: Yes, subquery supports it, in fact a subquery is nothing more than a field, it will have to be included in the external group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate inside `Shipment_item_container` and then join the result to 2 copies of `Shipment_item` and aggrgate:

```
SELECT sic.Container_id, sic.Shipment_item_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT si.Shipment_order_id) Shipment_order_ciount,
       COUNT(si.Shipment_order_id) Total_number_of_shipment_item
FROM (
  SELECT Container_id, Shipment_item, COUNT(*) Shipment_item_count 
  FROM Shipment_item_container 
  GROUP BY Container_id, Shipment_item
) sic
LEFT JOIN Shipment_item si ON si.Item_id = sic.Shipment_item
LEFT JOIN Shipment_item t ON t.Shipment_order_id = si.Shipment_order_id
GROUP BY sic.Container_id, sic.Shipment_item_count
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e0d77fc1093e20d0c45c51dd4678f18f).
Results:

```
> container_id | shipment_item_count | shipment_order_ciount | total_number_of_shipment_item
> :----------- | ------------------: | --------------------: | ----------------------------:
> A            |                   2 |                     1 |                             4
> B            |                   1 |                     0 |                             0
```